# Exporting strings without the quotes

Tags: export, csv-format

I'm trying to export the following string

```
"sep = ,"
```

to a CSV-file, as to be able to define the separation symbol.

However, when using the following command:

```
Export["test.csv", Join[{"sep = ,"}, RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {5, 3}]], "CSV"]
```

I get the quotes around the string in the first line:

```
"sep = ,"
-4,5,0
5,-4,-1
0,5,2
-1,2,4
-1,-4,-1
```

This obviously isn't recognized by Excel and it doesn't open correctly. I've tried changing the string to something like

```
Style["sep=,", ShowStringCharacters -> False]
```

and then export again, but then I just get this whole command into the CSV-file.

Is there a method to export this string without the quotes attached to them into a CSV-file?

Comment: AFAIK, strings can only be exported without the quotation marks if done via [streams](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html), as in `stream=OpenWrite[file];WriteString[stream, "string..."];Close@stream` or if `OpenWrite` is called with the option `FormatType -> OutputForm`, but that might cause unwanted formatting on other characters.

Comment: Of curiosity is there some software that actually needs that header? Undoubtedly it will break many things (eg Mathematica will just include it as a data line if you import..)

Comment: Actually, this is standard behavior for Excel exports to CSV too. If a string contains a field separator (a comma in this case) it needs to be quoted otherwise it will be seen (incorrectly) as a field separator upon import. Excel will automatically quote the string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 Export["test.csv", Join[{"sep = ,"}, 
        RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {5, 3}]], "TextDelimiters"->None]
```

(With the obvious issue if you also have strings that should be quoted in the data )

Answer (score 5):

If I try to create a CSV file without the first line indicating the seperator, the resulting file is readable by Excel.

```
 Export["test2.csv",RandomInteger[{-5,5},{5,3}]]
```

But if you still want the first line, I would do something like this

```
Export["test3.csv", 
 "sep = ,\n" <> ExportString[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {5, 3}], "CSV"]
 , "Text"]
```

Comment: Sadly, with my language settings, Excel wants ";" as delimiters. I've tried to change that, but that wasn't successful. Thanks for the good help!

Comment: Ahh, okay.  Another solution would be to export it as a `"Table"` but usint the `FieldSparators` option.  Like `Export["test.csv",RandomInteger[{-5,5},{5,3}],"Table","FieldSeparators"->" ; "]`

Comment: Another approach might be to export comma separated, but with a "txt" extension. I *think* then Excel will  pop up  a box and let you tell it what the delimiter is.