# How to export data to a plain text file?

Tags: export, files-and-directories, streams

I am preparing data used by a command line program. It requires data in a simpliest possible format:

```
value_x1 value_y1
value_x2 value_y2
...    
value_xN value_yN
```

For now I always need to use Python to process a datafile created in Mathematica that format, because Mathematica always adds quotes " or multiple blank spaces or tabs. How can I create a file in a format:

```
<value_x1><single_space_sign><value_y1><end_of_line_sign>
<value_x2><single_space_sign><value_y2><end_of_line_sign>
...    
<value_xN><single_space_sign><value_yN><end_of_line_sign>
```

`OpenWrite[]`, `Write[]`, `Export[,"Table"]` etc. produce files with additional characters, and therefore are useless without processing in Python.

Edit: What if I needed to create a file in a format:

```
<value_x1><single_space_sign><some string character><value_y1><end_of_line_sign>
<value_x2><single_space_sign><some string character><value_y2><end_of_line_sign>
...    
<value_xN><single_space_sign><some string character><value_yN><end_of_line_sign>
```

Edit 2: Proposed answer:

```
dat = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 4}] // N;
Export["test.dat", dat]
```

produces file containing following data:

```
{1., 0.8414709848078965}
{2., 0.9092974268256817}
{3., 0.1411200080598672}
{4., -0.7568024953079282}
```

Which is useless.

Comment: It won't work. First: arguments are misplaced. Second: it will return values in braces `{}`. What I am asking: is this "small variation" which I can't figure out.

Comment: it works on mac-os with 'Mathematica 9.0'

Comment: As usual... make difficult things in Mathematica easily, be unable to make simpliest things. Lol

Comment: also works in mathematica 8.0 and 7.0

Comment: I use Mathematica 9 on Windows 7 and 8. It works as mentioned in post.

Comment: try `Export["test.dat", dat, "Data"]` ? Or get a mac :-)

Comment: i agree @chris you have the argument order wrong, filename comes first.

Comment: Export::noelem: "\!\({\"Data\"}\) is not a valid set of export elements for the \!\(\"Text\"\) format."

Comment: @george2079 sure. Can't edit the comment… posted a working answer on macos at least

Comment: God bless Python....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python ?

Comment: I can do this in Python. I would like to have this ultra-mega-incredible feature also in mathematica :]

Comment: Well I cannot help you since I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(41047)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41047)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
dat = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 4}] // N;
Export["test.dat", dat]
```

So that

```
 FilePrint["test.dat"]
```

returns

(* 
1.  0.8414709848078965
2.  0.9092974268256817
3.  0.1411200080598672
4.  -0.7568024953079282
*)

Comment: It saves values in braces `{}` to a file: {x,y}

Answer (score 22):

```
dat = Table[{i, Sin[i], Cos[i], Tan[i]}, {i, 4}] // N;

Export["test.txt", dat, "Table",  "FieldSeparators" -> " "]

FilePrint["test.txt"]
```

> 1. 0.8414709848078965 0.5403023058681397 1.5574077246549023
> 2. 0.9092974268256817 -0.4161468365471424 -2.185039863261519
> 3. 0.1411200080598672 -0.9899924966004454 -0.1425465430742778
> 4. -0.7568024953079282 -0.6536436208636119 1.1578212823495777

Nothing new here. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: How can I insert there also a string so it appears without quote marks? `1. 0.84 0.54 " string" 1.55`

Comment: @misery Just put it in the `dat` list above. It gets exported without quotes.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries do you understand why my answer not work in windows as claimed?

Comment: @chris If I use a.txt extension for the file and your answer I get the behavior Misery reports. If I use .dat as extension one would think it works, but it actually uses tab characters as field separators. My guess is that Misery wrote to a .txt file which yields a different default behavior than to .dat files. By using "Table" as an explicit export format I overruled MMA's format guessing based on extension.

Comment: @Misery This also works for me in version 7 under Windows 7.  If I use e.g. `dat = {{1, "foo"}, {2.2, bar}, {Pi, -7.31*^134}}` there are no quotation marks around `foo` in the output.  Are you saying this does *not* work on your system?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this may be the issue, but specifying `"FieldSeparators"` to a space causes multi-word strings to be quoted:

```
 ExportString[{{1, 1}, {"dog", "and cat"}}, "Table",  "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
```

> 1 1
>
> dog "and cat"

Fix with `TextDelimiters`

```
 ExportString[{{1, 1}, {"dog", "and cat"}}, "Table", 
     "FieldSeparators" -> " ", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]
```

> 1 1
>
> dog and cat

Obviously you now can't simply read it back in as a table recovering the original strings.

(verifed for export to files under Windows using either a ".dat" extension, or the "Table" argument)

Comment: The quoting of fields that contain a field separator is a standard operating procedure. If this is not done fields cannot be correctly recognized anymore. Try, for instance, saving as CSV an Excel sheet with a text field containing a comma, among other characters.

Comment: I did find it in the docs: "By default, Export delimits text fields containing the field separator with double-quote characters." I will take that note out.