# Format table output

Tags: export, output-formatting, data-structures

I'm trying to make a quick code to give me coordinates of some circles to be read in *AUTOCAD*.

When I use the format `"Table"` or `"String"` to [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) it always gives me something like

```
{circle, 5.5, 57.5}
{circle, 5.5, 109.5}
{circle, 5.5, 161.5}
{circle, 18.5, 5.5}
```

and AUTOCAD only recognizes

```
circle 5.5,57.5 

circle 5.5,57.5 

circle 5.5,57.5
```

...

**How can I get rid of the `{}` and the undesired comma between circle and the numbers?**

Comment: `ExportString[Insert[#, ",", 3] & /@ data, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " ", Alignment -> Right]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExportString[{{circle, 5.5, 57.5},
  {circle, 5.5, 109.5},
  {circle, 5.5, 161.5},
  {circle, 18.5, 5.5}}
 , "TSV"
 , "TextDelimiters" -> ""
 ]
```

> ```
> circle    5.5 57.5
> circle    5.5 109.5
> circle    5.5 161.5
> circle    18.5    5.5
> ```

[image]
or

```
ExportString[{{circle, 5.5, 57.5},
  {circle, 5.5, 109.5},
  {circle, 5.5, 161.5},
  {circle, 18.5, 5.5}}
 , "Table"
 ]
```

You may be interested on looking into the options: `Alignment`, `CharacterEncoding` and `"FieldSeparators"` too.

You can use [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) instead of [`ExportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString.html) to save into a file

Answer (score -1):

You might find useful this question: [How to export data to a plain text file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/how-to-export-data-to-a-plain-text-file)

In the end, the option field separators is the one option that you might be looking for as they said before.